# Prioritise spotlight search results in El Capitan

Tags: macos, spotlight, search

It seems this feature has been scrapped for el capitan. I'm a designer so I want all images to appear at the top of the search results. Anyone worked out a hack for this?

Answer (score 1):

In System Settings > Spotlight > Search Results, disable as many items as you can.